# How can I convert a boolean table to one hot vectors efficiently?

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding

Let's say I have a table looking something like this -

```
Movie        Action      Scifi       Drama          Romance
Abc           True       False       False            False
Def           False      False        True            False
Ghi           False      False       False            True
```

I would like to convert it to one hot vectors such that

```
Abc - [1   0    0   0]'
Def - [0   0    1   0]'
Ghi - [0   0    0   1]'
```

It is known that only one of the columns can be True.

Is there can efficient way to do this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found a way to do this for bigger datasets.

```
df['genre'] = pd.Series(np.random.randn(size), index=df.index)
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i]['action'] == True:
        df.at[i, 'genre'] = 0        
    elif df.iloc[i]['scifi'] == True:
        df.at[i, 'genre'] = 1
    elif df.iloc[i]['drama'] == True:
        df.at[i, 'genre'] = 2
    elif df.iloc[i]['romance'] == True:
        df.at[i, 'genre'] = 3
```

So, by doing this, we will make a new column in the dataframe called 'genre' and give it appropriate values. After that,

```
y = df['genre']
import tensorflow as tf
y_categorical = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y)
```

This would do the job of converting it to one hot vectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

Abc = np.array([True,False,False,False])
Def = np.array([False,False,True,False])
Ghi = np.array([False,False,False,True])
movies = np.array([Abc, Def, Ghi])
print("Input:")
print(movies)

#casting from boolean to integer
result  = np.array(movies, dtype=np.int)

print("Output:")
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not sure if this would be feasible for a huge dataset. Do check my answer.

Comment: Your answer seems fine too. How large is your dataset? How many rows/columns do you have?